# Can't implement new Button in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

I would like to implement a new JButton in my class, but I don't get a solution. I have the "add(b10)" in the code listet below, and it fills out the whole windows of the application, but I just want it to be a single small button on top. If I remove "add(b10)", I can't see the button anymore. Do you have any solutions? I just want the bottom to stay on top of the window.

Thanks a lot.

```
    package de.hhu.propra.teamA4;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Game extends Panel{


    JButton b10;

    private int array[][];
    private MainMenu first;
    private Level level;

    public Game(){


        first = new MainMenu();

        b10 = new JButton("New Game");
        b10.setVisible(true);
        add(b10)

        first.setTitle("Worms");
        first.setSize(800,500);
        first.setDefaultCloseOperation(MainMenu.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        first.setVisible(true);
        first.setResizable(false);
        first.rungame();
        array = new int[800][500];
        run();
}

public void run(){
       Level level = first.getlevel();
       fillArray(level);

   }
public void fillArray(Level level){
       Ground[] ground = level.getground();
       Obstacle[] obstacles = level.getobstacles();

for (Obstacle currobstacle : obstacles){
           int obstaclex = currobstacle.getx();
           int obstacley = currobstacle.gety();
           int obstaclewidth = currobstacle.getwidth();
           int obstacleheight = currobstacle.getheight();
           int obs = currobstacle.isdestructable() ? 2 : 1;

           for (int y = obstacley; y<obstacley+obstacleheight;y++){
               for (int x = obstaclex; x<obstaclex+obstaclewidth;x++){
                   array[x][y]=obs;
               }
           }
       }

       for (Ground currground : ground){
           int groundstartx = currground.getstartx();
           int groundstarty = currground.getstarty();
           int groundendx = currground.getendx();
           int groundendy = currground.getendy();
           for(int i = groundstartx; i <= groundendx; i++){
               double slope = (double)(groundendy - groundstarty)/(groundendx - groundstartx);
               int currgroundy = (int) (groundstarty+slope*(i-groundstartx));
               for (int j = 0; j < (int) slope+1; j++){
                   array[i][currgroundy+j]=1;
               }               
           }
       }
   }


}
```

Comment: you may want to take a look at layoutmanagers and their influence on your screen when you add components, how they are added and how the result 'll look

Answer (score 2):

Add the button in `JPanel` first then add the panel in `JFrame`

JFrame by default uses `BorderLayout` and this layout by default adds the component in the center that covers the whole available space.

If you want to add more components then use a container to add all of them then finally add that container in `JFrame`.

#### [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)